# Do I have to implement a partial parser, to support dot triggered completion request?

Tags: language-server-protocol

Testing with VSCode 1.52.1 / LSP 3.16

I enabled dot to trigger completion like:

```json
        'completionProvider': {
          'triggerCharacters': [
            '.', '@',
          ]
        },
```

But seems `textDocument/didChange` is sent before the completion request, with the dot insertion, it renders the whole source being invalid syntax, so I lost AST to work out desired completion response.

Is this norm? How other implementations are dealing this scenario? They all implement a partial parser to get partial AST with invalid dot standing there? Or other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Partial AST is probably the cleanest way of doing it. You could also manually try to iterate backwards in the input until you find the start of the expression being “dotted”, parse that as an expression, and then use a previously known good AST to look up the type and provide completions